# How to bind a List<string[]> to a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, data-binding, gridview

I can't find an answer anywhere... I have a List<string[]> populated like this:

```
...
while (myReader.Read())
{
    string[] row = new string[myInt];

    for (int i = 0; i < myInt; i++)
    {
        row[i] = myReader[i].ToString();
    }

    myList.Add(row);    
}
...
```

How do I bind this list to a gridview with TemplateField columns?

Comment: `mygridview.datasource = mylist;` `mygridview.databind();`

Comment: @JonH How to reference the columns in the TemplateField? Does it work with indices as Field names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier way is to create an anonymous class and bind that to your GridView. Example:

```
var query = from c in row
            select new { SomeProperty = c };

GridView.DataSource=query;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: This works. But if I go with this, how would I handle gridview paging? This data source does not support server-side data paging.

Comment: You don't. If you need to take advantage of all of these complicated features for a single list, you need to rethink your method of storage. How many rows of a single string do you have that you need pagination?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `RowDataBound` event of the `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="gridView1_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When binding your data:

```
var myStrings = new List<string[]>
                      {
                          new [] { "hello", "bye"},
                          new [] { "1", "2"}
                      };

gridView1.DataSource = myStrings;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

`RowDataBound` event:

```
public void gvDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        return;
    }

    var item = (string[]) e.Row.DataItem;
    Label myLabel = e.Row.FindControl("myLabel") as Label;
    myLabel.Text = item[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use databind as you normally would. To reference the column, it goes by index by default. So like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="rpt">
<Columns>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Key") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</Columns>
</asp:Repeater>

Dictionary<string, string> lst = new Dictionary<string, string>();
lst.Add("test", String.Empty);
lst.Add("test1", String.Empty);
this.rpt.DataSource = lst;
this.rpt.DataBind();
```

Comment: The gridview uses TemplateField columns

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Use a repeater.

Comment: I guess that doesn't really work either. K, one other thing you can do is make it a dictionary

Comment: Dictionary is really light weight so you don't have to the route of a data table.